# Loopsteps are getting skipped when if statement is inserted

Tags: gnuplot

I'm puzzled about the behaviour of my plotting script. I want to plot multiple files. In the last file i want different border settings. So i came up with an if statement. The script looks like:

```
labeltitles = "0.01 0.02 0.05 0.1 0.15 0.1885 0.2 0.25"
outnames = "0p01 0p02 0p05 0p1 0p15 0p1885 0p2 0p25"
do for [i=1:2] {
    set border 4 + 1                                    ## top (4) + bottom (1)
    if (i = words(labeltitles)) {set border 8 + 4 + 1}  ## right (8) + top (4) + bottom (1)}
    set xlabel 'z = '.word(labeltitles,i)
    set out word(outnames,i).'.eps'
    plot 'data.dat' u (column(i+1)):1 w l lt 1 lw 7 lc rgb '#444444'
}
```

When i run this script, only the last plot gets outputted. If i comment the if statement all plots get outputted. I also tried to add the else statement, but nothing changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A rather classical programming error: You have an assignment inside the `if`-condition instead of a comparison (`==`). It must be

```
if (i == words(labeltitles)) {set border 8 + 4 + 1}
```

Comment: You are right. But why is the last loopstep executed in the right manner then and the others not?

Comment: I don't know what you mean. Changing the assignment to a comparison should work fine (besides that you must iterate over all words and not only 1 and 2: `do for [i=1:words(labeltitles)]...`.

Comment: Yes, it really works fine. In my original file i have, what u mentioned last. I only tried to make an easier version for the forum. Thank you very much.